# Number of integral solutions to $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 =30$ with $y_i \ge 2$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

How many solutions there are to the given equation that satisfy the given condition: $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 =30$, each $y_i$ is an integer that is at least $2$.

I don't know how to start this question.

Comment: Same as the number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=22$ in non-negative integers. Is that a familiar problem?

Comment: Did you mean $y_{\color{red}{1}} + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 = 30$?

Comment: Use Andre's hint, then read about [combinations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition).